# Code not running in parallel when using thread::scoped

Tags: rust

Can someone please explain why the code below does not run in parallel? I guess I don't understand how `thread::scoped` works..

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::time::Duration;
use std::old_io::timer;

fn main() {
    let buf = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<String>::new()));
    let res = test(buf);
    println!("{:?}", *res.lock().unwrap());
}

fn test(buf: Arc<Mutex<Vec<String>>>) -> Arc<Mutex<Vec<String>>> {
    let guards: Vec<_> = (0..3).map( |i| {
        let mtx = buf.clone();
        thread::scoped(|| {
            println!("Thread: {}", i);
            let mut res = mtx.lock().unwrap();
            timer::sleep(Duration::seconds(5));
            res.push(format!("thread {}", i));
        });
    }).collect();
    buf
}
```

The code is based on the examples [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/intro.html#concurrency) where it's stated:

> The scoped function takes one argument, a closure, indicated by the double bars ||. This closure is executed in a new thread created by scoped. The method is called scoped because it returns a 'join guard', which will automatically join the child thread when it goes out of scope. Because we collect these guards into a Vec, and that vector goes out of scope at the end of our program, our program will wait for every thread to finish before finishing.

Thanks

Comment: I've submitted [a PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23202) to fix the original docs.

Comment: Since this question keeps coming up for me: thread::scoped was [abandoned for a good reason](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-does-thread-spawn-need-static-lifetime-for-generic-bounds/4541) and the alternative mentioned there is `thread` [in the crossbeam crate](https://docs.rs/crossbeam).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a tricky case. The problem is the humble semicolon. Look at this minimized code:

```
thread::scoped(|| {});
```

That semicolon means that the result of the `collect` *isn't* a vector of `JoinGuard`s — it's a `Vec<()>`! Each `JoinGuard` is dropped immediately, forcing the thread to finish before the next iteration starts.

When you fix this issue, you'll hit the next problem, which is that `i` and `mtx` don't live long enough. You'll need to `move` them into the closure:

```
thread::scoped(move || {})
```

Comment: Looks like this `JoinGuard` is a candidate for `#[must_use]` mabye?

Comment: @sellibitze certainly seems like that could be a good possibility! What's the right process for that?

Comment: Try pitching it to the core devs in `#rust-internals` and see what happens, I guess. :)